# How to force the browser to download only part of an audio/video element?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have an `audio` element that I control through JavaScript:

```
<audio preload="metadata" src="myfile.mp3" />

<button type="button">Play/Pause</button>

// JS logic not relevant to the question
```

Let's say `myfile.mp3` is a 5-minute audio and after I play the first 10 seconds of it, I call `pause()` to prevent the rest of it from being played. It seems like the browser continues downloading the rest of the file. How can I prevent this from happening and download only a specific chunk of the file?

Comment: A 5 minute wav file is huge. Convert it to mp3.

Comment: That wasn't my question at all.

Comment: Yeah, I posted a comment not an answer, so yeah wav files are huge and mp3 have compression algorithm that makes a wave file a mere fraction of it's size. It's a waste of time to play such an antiquated format over the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const mediaElement = document.querySelector("#myMediaElementID");
mediaElement.removeAttribute("src");
mediaElement.load();
```

> By removing the media element's src attribute and invoking the load() method, you release the resources associated with the audio/video, which stops the network download. You must call load() after removing the attribute, because just removing the src attribute does not invoke the load algorithm.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery